Hitchhikers Guide: was Marvin the computer that Deep Thought said would follow it?
I think Marvin was the great computer that Deep Thought said would come after him. There's all sorts of hints in the story.

Earth was created by the mice on Magrathea to find out the question that 42 was the answer of. All the humans were a big neural network.
Marvin says, "I have a brain the size of a planet"

And in the British TV version, on Magrethea, all the people are in the dining room, but Marvin can be seen two stories down in the research department consulting with the mice. On Magrathea, he spends all his time with the mice. He delivered the only humans left that might have the answer. And they did.
So am I right? Was Marvin the computer Deep Thought referred to?

Well, no. It's explicitly stated that the computer is Earth.

"I speak of none but the computer that is to come after me,” intoned Deep Thought, his voice regaining its accustomed declamatory tones. “A computer whose merest operational parameters I am not worthy to calculate — and yet I will design it for you. A computer that can calculate the Question to the Ultimate Answer, a computer of such infinite and subtle complexity that organic life itself shall form part of its operational matrix. And you yourselves shall take on new forms and go down into the computer to navigate its ten-million-year program! Yes! I shall design this computer for you. And I shall name it also unto you. And it shall be called... the Earth."

Marvin doesn't literally have a brain the size of a planet.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jLIRJwfZhg

It was part of Marvin's brain

I don't know what that clip is supposed to demonstrate. We know Marvin says he has a brain the size of a planet, but he's just exaggerating. And how could the Earth be part of his brain? This is well before he does any time travel, and we know that he - like all the cybernetics on the Heart of Gold - is brand new, yet the Earth has been around for 10 million years at this point.

ISTR that one of the many versions of HHGG said that Marvin's brain is in another dimension, and is literally the size of a planet. Anyone else recall this, or is it a Mandella effect?
